# Re-assinging an "auto_ptr" and Managing Memory

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, auto-ptr

I've a situation like this:

```
class MyClass
{
private:
  std::auto_ptr<MyOtherClass> obj;

public:
  MyClass()
  {
    obj = auto_ptr<MyOtherClass>(new MyOtherClass());
  }

  void reassignMyOtherClass()
  {
    // ... do funny stuff
    MyOtherClass new_other_class = new MyOtherClass();
    // Here, I want to:
    //  1) Delete the pointer object inside 'obj'
    //  2) Re-assign the pointer object of 'obj' to 'new_other_class'
    //     so that 'obj' now manages 'new_other_class' instead of the
    //     object that just got deleted manually
  }
};
```

Is there a way to achieve this? Will the following code do what I want?

```
void MyClass::reassignMyOtherClass()
{
  // ... still, do more funny stuff (flashback humor :-)
  MyOtherClass new_other_class = new MyOtherClass();
  obj.reset(new_other_class);
}
```

Will the memory of `new_other_class` be de-allocated in the default destructor of `MyClass`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it will.
You can use

```
obj.reset( new MyOtherClass() );
```

And I'd better use such constructor

```
 MyClass():
     obj( new MyOtherClass() )
 {
 }
```

Comment: Mykola, thank you! I'm so used to Java that I find the constructor initialization list repulsive, as if I don't trust that it assigns the right values :)  A question though: can we use initialization list even if the object disallows copy construction? May be this is why I don't trust this :)

Comment: It doesn't use copy constructor. It uses constructor.

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b84a89af(VS.80).aspx) where describing `reset`

> The member function evaluates the expression delete myptr, but only if the stored pointer value myptr changes as a result of function call. It then replaces the stored pointer with ptr.

It will do what you want.